Movie about a boy with bad legs who joins the army and starts a fishing business
In the movie, the hero tells his story from a bus station.
When he was a little boy his mother told him to run and run and his legs would become regular. After that, he completes his graduation from college by running in a rugby game. He then joins the army, but his commander loses his legs.
Later, he becomes a star of table-tennis. He starts a fishing business and gives some money to his passed-away army friend. His commander gets some high-level prosthetic legs, and say thanks for saving his life. 
At the end of the film, he finally reunites with the girl he loves.

You're looking for Forrest Gump:

In 1981, Forrest Gump (Tom Hanks), a man with below-average
  intelligence, watches a feather fall from the sky at a bus stop in
  Savannah, Georgia.
One day, while fleeing from bullies, Forrest's leg braces break apart
  and he discovers that he can run very fast. A few years later, Forrest
  inadvertently runs onto the field during a local high school football
  match and catches the attention of Coach Bryant from the University of
  Alabama who is scouting for players. Forrest attends the university on
  an athletic scholarship and becomes a college football star, earning
  him a spot on the College Football All-America Team and a trip to the
  White House to meet President John F. Kennedy.
After graduating, Forrest enlists in the United States Army, where he
  befriends former shrimp fisherman Benjamin Buford "Bubba" Blue
  (Mykelti Williamson), and they agree to go into the shrimping business
  together once they end their service. Jenny (Robin Wright) meanwhile
  had gotten herself thrown out of college after she exposes herself on
  the cover of Playboy Magazine and "fulfills" her aspirations of
  becoming a famous folk singer by performing nude at a strip club.
  Forrest goes to one of her shows after seeing the cover and intervenes
  when she is harassed by club patrons. He tells her that his unit is
  being sent to Vietnam so Jenny tells Forrest that if he is ever in
  trouble: run. Once they arrive in Vietnam, they are assigned to First
  Lieutenant Dan Taylor (Gary Sinise). One day while on patrol their
  platoon is ambushed. Forrest carries several wounded soldiers to
  safety including Lieutenant Dan and his friend Bubba, but Bubba is
  severely wounded and dies shortly thereafter. Forrest himself is also
  wounded in the buttocks and Lieutenant Dan, who has had both of his
  legs amputated due to his injuries, is furious at Forrest for leaving
  him a cripple and cheating him out of his destiny to die in battle, as
  all of his ancestors had.
Forrest discovers an aptitude for ping pong and begins playing for the
  U.S. Army team, eventually competing against Chinese teams on a
  goodwill tour.
Forrest is discharged from the military as a sergeant and uses money
  from a ping pong endorsement to buy a shrimping boat, fulfilling his
  wartime promise to Bubba. Lieutenant Dan keeps his own promise and
  joins Forrest as first mate. They initially have little luck, but
  after Hurricane Carmen wrecks every other shrimping boat in the
  region, the Bubba Gump Shrimp Company becomes a huge success. Both of
  them are wealthy.

